# jQuery Success Function doesn't alert

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, web-services

here is the problem, I have the following function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#selectTypeDD').change(function() {
    var type = $("#selectTypeDD option:selected").text();
    changeType(type);
    alert(type);
});
});
```

The alert prints out `pub` when I choose city of my drop down menu.

changeType is this function

```
function changeType(type)
{
$.ajax
({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'webservice.php',
    data: {type: type},
    success: function(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        alert("SUCCESS");
    }
});
}
```

I get this result here in Firebug

```
pub[{"name":"The Master Builder","lon":"-1.34532","lat":"50.9303"},{"name":"Goblets","lon":"-1.40455","lat":"50.9088"},{"name":"Rat and Parrot","lon":"-1.40442","lat":"50.9085"},{"name":"The Victory Inn","lon":"-1.31415","lat":"50.8588"},{"name":"The King and Queen","lon":"-1.31356","lat":"50.8586"}
```

The list goes on and on, but I think those are the most important ones. The problem is now, that I want to do something with the result and it didn't work, so I tested why it is so, and typed in the `alert("SUCCESS")` in the success-function. But it doesn't even print out the alert. Why? What am I doing wrong? The werbservice runs without problems. When I open my site localhost/blabla/webservice.php?type=pub it prints out everything. So what could be the problem?

Here is the party of my webservice

```
else if(isset($_GET['type']))
{
$type = $_GET['type'];
echo $type;
if($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT name, lon, lat FROM pointsofinterest WHERE type = '".$type."'"))
{
    $tempArray = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($array, $tempArray); 
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
}
}
```

Comment: did you try the ``error`` callback yet?

Comment: source : function(request, response) you can try this .

Comment: put alert in `error: function(response)` to make sure your server call is working properly

Comment: Yes, I'm getting an error. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
success: function(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
```

to

```
success: function(response)
```

Comment: Still nothing. No `alert("SUCCESS"); `